# Strawberry Perl - Search and replace in Windows

Tags: windows, perl, replace, strawberry-perl

I am trying to execute the following command:

`perl -pi -e 's,vaadin-element,color-picker,g' *.* demo/* test/* src/* theme/*/*`
*(following [this](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-element-skeleton/blob/master/README_CREATE_NEW.md) document)*

Unfortunately it seems that the window distribution of pearl I use has some issues with the command, as I get the following error:

```
Can't open *.*: Invalid argument.
Can't open demo/*: Invalid argument.
Can't open test/*: Invalid argument.
Can't open src/*: Invalid argument.
Can't open theme/*/*: Invalid argument.
```

Any suggestions on how to fix that?
Thank you in advance!

***Disclaimer:*** I never used pearl before and have absolutely no experience.

Comment: It seems to work fine from the Cygwin terminal, I guess you are using the command prompt?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, Cygwin is an environment that emulates unix; you can't think of it as Windows.

Comment: @ikegami Ok thanks, I am new to Windows terminology :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In unix systems, the shell expands globs and passes the file names to the program.

```
$ perl -e'CORE::say for @ARGV' *
file1
file2
```

The Windows shell, on the other hand, passes the values as is, and leaves it up to the program to treat them as globs if so desired.

```
>perl -e"CORE::say for @ARGV" *
*
```

You can perform the globbing as follows:

```
>perl -MFile::DosGlob=glob -e"BEGIN { @ARGV = map glob, @ARGV } CORE::say for @ARGV" *
file1
file2
```

The `BEGIN` block isn't generally needed, but it will ensure the globing once and early enough when using `-n` (which is implied by `-p`).

The `-MFile::DosGlob=glob` makes `glob` have Windows-like semantics. For example, it causes `*.*` to match all files, even if they don't contain `.`.

Integrated:

```
perl -i -MFile::DosGlob=glob -pe"BEGIN { @ARGV = map glob, @ARGV } s,vaadin-element,color-picker,g" *.* demo/* test/* src/* theme/*/*
```

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation and solution snippet!

Answer (score 1):

In Unix-derived operating systems, the shell expands globs like `*.*`, and provides the command line as an array of strings to the program.

In Windows, the command line is a single string, and it is up to the program to interpret what it means, including things like quote characters and globs. If the program is a normal C program, the C runtime interprets command line, and expands the globs, and passes an array of strings to `main`. This is because the C standard requires this.

However Perl is not C. Use the `File::Glob` library to expand the arguments.