# How can I adapt a unix Perl command to Windows?

Tags: windows, perl

In https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/install-sample-schemas. Tim Hall proposes the following command (once positioned in a particular directory) to replace the string `__SUB__CWD__` by the name of the current directory in sql files and dat files:

```
cd ...
perl -p -i.bak -e 's#__SUB__CWD__#'$(pwd)'#g' *.sql */*.sql */*.dat
```

How can adapt this command for Windows?
Even if the name of directory is constant (ex: *C:\app\soutou\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\demo\schema*). I am not a user of Perl (Oracle dev)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) on your windows box this command should just work from the cmd.com shell

```
perl -i.bak -MCwd -pe"BEGIN{ $cwd = cwd; @ARGV = map glob, @ARGV; } s#__SUB__CWD__#$cwd#g" *.sql *\*.sql *\*.dat
```

Comment: Thanks but with Active Perl this command returns `Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.`

Comment: It might be a long shot, but I remember `cmd.exe` having problems with single quotes.  Try replacing them with double quotes: `perl -MCwd -p -i.bak -e "BEGIN{ $cwd = cwd } s#__SUB__CWD__#$cwd#g" *.sql *\*.sql *\*.dat`

Comment: Thanks it produces now  `Can't open *.sql: Invalid argument.
Can't open *\*.sql: Invalid argument.
Can't open *\*.dat: Invalid argument.`

Comment: @ChristianSoutou See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56354760/2173773)

Comment: @Hakon Haegland, thanks you're right,it works with a single file name (as test.sql instead of *.sql). I'm gonna try with Cygwin

Comment: Updated line so it should now expand file globs

Comment: It works with Cygwin, to avoid the string (/cygdrive/C) coming from the path, I adjusted the original command with the path of the Oracle directory. 
`perl -p -i.bak -e 's#__SUB__CWD__#'C:/oracle_directory...'#g'  *.sql */*.sql */*.dat`

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle RDBMS on Windows you can use insteat of the perl method :

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include "*.sql","*.dat" | ForEach-Object { $a = $_.fullname; ( Get-Content $a ) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "__SUB__CWD__","<%ORACLE_HOME%>demo\schema" } | Set-Content $a }
```

* replace `<%ORACLE_HOME%>` with your Oracle_Home.